# Zorin doesn't install Dell firmware update

Tags: upgrade, firmware, software-updates, zorin

Regularly, I'm notified by Zorin's Software app that a Dell firmware update is available. It's always `v1.11.0` > `v1.25.0`.

When clicking on “Install”, I'm asked to re-boot the system. After doing so, the update notification in the Software app is gone. However, after a couple of days it always re-appears.

Trying to upgrade using Gnome Firmware fails too.

What can I do about this? Thanks!

```
OS: Zorin 16.2 (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS)
Linux kernel: 5.15.0-71-generic
CPU: 11th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-1165G7 @ 2.80GHz × 8
```

[image: firmware update in Software]

[image: Gnome Firmware]

[image: Gnome Firmware]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to manually install the firmware update from a USB stick, following [Dell's documentation](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000131486/update-the-dell-bios-in-a-linux-or-ubuntu-environment).

> ## Summary
>
> 1. Get a USB drive and format it to FAT32. This will wipe all data on the USB drive.
> 2. Download the BIOS update from https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us?app=drivers. It's supposed to be an `.exe` file, even if you're running Linux. (This file is for the BIOS, not for your operating system.)
> 3. Power off the system.
> 4. Reboot and press `F12` at the Dell splash screen.
> 5. In the one-time boot menu, select the option `BIOS Flash Update`.
> 6. Navigate to your USB disk and select the `.exe` downloaded previously.
> 7. Wait until the update is finished. Done!

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note that [link-only answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) are discouraged, as the link may become invalid or the linked content change. Please edit your answer to include at least a summary of the linked explanation.